# Using one prompt input for two different functions

Tags: bash, video, environment-variables

I would like to make a time lapse movie in a specific range.
The script is working until it makes the movie.
Here the script:

```
    read -p "Von welchem Zeitraum soll der Zeitrafferfilm sein? (JJJJMMTT): " begin
begin=$begin

read -p "Bis wann soll der Film gehen? (JJJJMMTT)" end
end=$end                   

if [ ! -d Zeitraffer ]

then
echo "Ordner Zeitraffer erzeugt"

/bin/mkdir Zeitraffer

fi

sleep 3

cp *$begin-1200*.jpg ./Zeitraffer

while [ $begin != $end ] 

do

begin=`date +"%Y%m%d" -d "$begin +1 day"`

    echo "Kopiere Bild Schedule_$begin-1200*.jpg in den Zeitrafferordner"

        cp *$begin-1200*.jpg ./Zeitraffer

done  

  cd Zeitraffer
    echo "Erzeuge Zeitraffer$begin"-"$end.avi"

  $(ffmpeg -r 12 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -c:v libx264 Zeitraffer$begin"-"$end.avi)
```

One of the variables "$begin" is changing its value due to copy the range of pictures into a temporary folder. The range of the pictures is correct but then the time lapse movie name is `$(ffmpeg -r 12 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -c:v libx264 Zeitraffer$begin"-"$end.avi)`
Logically the "$begin" is getting the"$end" also so the file looks like for example: Zeitraffer20150131-20150131.avi
Is there a way to use the first prompt also as some fixed value so I can use it at the end to make the movie? It should look like Zeitraffer20150101-20150131.avi

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Thanks Cyrus but the script is running thru without errors. Only the filename of the movie is not like I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `begin=$begin` and `end=$end` commands don't do anything at all, so lose them. Second, rather than incrementing `$begin` as you go through the loop, create another variable (e.g. `$current`) for the day it currently working on; set it to `$begin` at the beginning, and stop when it equals `$end`:

```
current=$begin
cp *$current-1200*.jpg ./Zeitraffer

while [ $current != $end ]; do

    current=`date +"%Y%m%d" -d "$current +1 day"`
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! That worked. Now it looks like:

```
   #!/bin/bash

read -p "Von welchem Zeitraum soll der Zeitrafferfilm sein? (JJJJMMTT): " begin
begin=$begin

read -p "Bis wann soll der Film gehen? (JJJJMMTT)" end
end=$end                   

if [ ! -d Zeitraffer ]

then
echo "Ordner Zeitraffer erzeugt"

/bin/mkdir Zeitraffer

fi

current=$begin

  cp *$current-1200*.jpg ./Zeitraffer

while [ $current != $end ]; do

    current=`date +"%Y%m%d" -d "$current +1 day"`

    echo "Kopiere Bild Schedule_$current-1200*.jpg in den Zeitrafferordner"

    cp *$current-1200*.jpg ./Zeitraffer
done  

  cd Zeitraffer
    echo "Erzeuge Zeitraffer$begin"-"$end.avi"

  $(ffmpeg -r 12 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -c:v libx264 Zeitraffer$begin"-"$end.avi)  
rm *.jpg # Löscht die temporär kopierten Bilder
echo "Temporäre Bilder wurden gelöscht."
```